# Helix 3D Toolkit - An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to load a 3d model into WPF's 3d view using

```
Model3DGroup groupLoad = HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter.Load("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\sc.3ds");
```

Yet it throws me

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter.Load(string)'
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `ModelImporter.Load` is not a static method. Hence you would have to create a `ModelImporter` instance first:

```
var importer = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.ModelImporter();
var groupLoad = importer.Load("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\sc.3ds");
```